# Any way to use TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in Android 4?

Tags: android, ssl, cryptography

I'm trying to access a server that requires clients to use the TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher. Android 5.0 supports this cipher in its AndroidOpenSSL provider but earlier versions (contrary to the JavaDoc) don't support it. I looked through the KitKat source and it appears to be supported in the openssl libraries. I believe they may also be part of earlier JB releases as well.

Is there a way to expose or trick the AndroidOpenSSL provider to use these cipher algorithms in Kitkat or even earlier 4.x releases? Perhaps some magic using the reflection APIs? I notice that the static hashmaps OPENSSL_TO_STANDARD_CIPHER_SUITES and STANDARD_TO_OPENSSL_CIPHER_SUITES are public in NativeCrypto.java. Is it as simple as finding away to add that mapping to those hashmaps or is there some other linkage that is required?

Comment: Did you try to look at spongycastle(compiled version of bouncycastle for android)?